Is the relationship of the radical axis of two circles to their tangent parabola already known?
Frankly, I did not want to publish this question on the site because I have the full proof, but I nevertheless publish it because I would like to know whether this important feature that I came up with is already known or not, so what I am looking for in this question is a reference that mentions this property if it is known, and if someone has an engineering proof, he is welcomed in the answers, so far I have proof of analytical geometry only
If we have two circles in a parabola, each touching the parabola at two points, then the midpoint of the centers of the two circles is a distance from the radical axis of these two circles, a distance equal to the distance between the focal point and the guide in the parabola.
In the image below:
The green dot is the focus of the parabola and the green line is the guide of the parabola. The blue dot is the midpoint between the centers of the two circles. The blue line is the radical axis of the two circles. The red and purple dots represent the centers and points of contact of the two circles.
The four dimensions between points on the axis of symmetry and between lines of the same color are equal

This is my proof using coordinate geometry in Arabic:



In the last image, it shows how you took advantage of the property to create a circle passing through a known point and touching a parabola at two points (there are two of these circles).

I came up with this theorem almost two years ago.

I'll note that your result generalizes to arbitrary (non-circle) conics. If $O$ is a focus, $H$ and $K$ the centers of two tangent circles, and $D$ and $R$ the points where the conic's axis meets the focus' associated directrix and the circles' radical axis, then we have
$$\frac1{2e^2}\left(;|OH|+|OK|;\right) + |OD| = |OR| $$
where $e\neq0$ is the eccentricity, and the distances are considered "signed" (which is especially important for making things work with hyperbolas). For a parabola, $e=1$, so that the first term reduces to $|OM|$, where $M$ is the midpoint of $H$ and $K$.

Come to think of it ... Using notation from my previous comment, as point $K$ approaches $H$, the radical axis approaches the line through the points where $\bigcirc H$ is tangent to the conic, so that $R$ approaches the midpoint of that "chord of tangency". The relation reduces a property of a single tangent circle:
$$\frac{1}{e^2}|OH|+|OD|=|OR|$$

Thank you @blue, although I have generalized a lot of parabola properties to all conic segments but I have not passed seriously enough to generalize this property to other conic segments, a beautiful generalization and has practical uses
